# regex match entries that display more than 3 weeks

Tags: java, regex, cisco

I get a string about an uptime of a device that looks like this:

```
swLUZ01 uptime is 1 year, 11 weeks, 1 day, 11 hours, 9 minutes
```

I built a regex that matches the first 2 entries and puts them in a group:

```
(\D+\d+) uptime is (\d+ \w+\, \d+ \w+)
```

This works so far. Now i would like to only capture devices, that are up for longer than 3 weeks. In this example, it works with following regex:

```
(\D+\d+) uptime is (\d+ \w+\, ([3-9]|\d{2}) weeks)
```

But this only works if the years and weeks come in the same order every time. Sadly, the devices uptime can look like this:

```
swLUZ01 uptime is 4 weeks, 5 days, 14 hours, 2 minutes
swLUZ01 uptime is 1 week, 2 days, 9 hours, 55 minutes
swLUZ01 uptime is 1 hour, 16 minutes
```

So the pronounciation changes from weeks to week if singular. Is there a regex that gives me a match if there are more than x weeks? It shouldnt give a match if there are no weeks found at all. I need the result in a group as i am referencing this later on in my rulebook. (Prime Infrastructure Compliance Audit Policies)

Comment: did you want something like that https://regex101.com/r/ecpo5R/7

Comment: It does the matching part correctyl, but there is no capturing group i could use later on...

Comment: which part did you want to capture and when to use?

Comment: `swLUZ01 uptime is 4 weeks, 5 days, 14 hours, 2 minutes` should give me back `4 weeks, 5 days` in a capturing group. `swLUZ01 uptime is 1 year, 11 weeks, 1 day, 11 hours, 9 minutes` should give me back `1 year, 11 weeks` in a capturing group.

Comment: There are many clauses to this, and must be captured:
- 1 year 2 weeks
- 3 weeks 2 days
- 3 weeks 20 minutes

So, I'd suggest to not to make a complex regex rather, extract the values and then compare

Comment: @Kamal Nayan: Sadly, I am working on compliance policies within Prime Infrastructure from Cisco. I can only use Java based Regex for this. No chance to use functions or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with following regex:

```
(\D+\d+) uptime is ((\d+ years?\,\s)\d+ \w+)|(([3-9]|\d{2}) weeks\,\s\d+ \w+)
```

This gives me back 2 values in a capturing (bold) in following examples:

```
swLUZ01 uptime is 11 weeks, 1 day, 11 hours, 9 minutes
```

gives back: **11 weeks, 1 day**

```
swLUZ01 uptime is 1 year, 1 week, 1 day, 11 hours, 9 minutes
```

gives back: **1 year, 1 week**

```
swLUZ01 uptime is 2 years, 11 weeks, 1 day, 11 hours, 9 minutes
```

gives back: **2 years, 11 weeks**

and it does not match following examples:

```
swLUZ01 uptime is 2 weeks, 1 day, 11 hours, 9 minutes
swLUZ01 uptime is 5 days, 11 hours, 9 minutes
```

Comment: simplified it with the capturing groups so that the uptime is always matched in the same group 2 `(\D+\d+) uptime is (\d+ years?\,\s\d+ \w+|[3-9]|\d{2} weeks\,\s\d+ \w+)`

Comment: Had to put the OR statement into brackets, but used a non capturing group as i dont need the content of this match: `(\w+) uptime is (\d+ years?\,\s\d+ \w+|(?:[3-9]|\d{2}) weeks\,\s\d+ \w+)`

Comment: I think the regex will be more readable/maintainable if you use logic on the captured weeks count rather than embedding a way to identify numbers greater than 2 into the regex itself.